# Declaring an objects variable as a new object error - PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, object

Firstly is it possible to get an extended class into a variable inside a class, something like below,

```
class EG extends DH {

     public $var = // VALUE OF DH
}
```

Secondly the way I have been doing it,

```
class EG {

     public $var;
     public function __construct() {
         $this -> var = new DH();
     }
}
```

The reason for this is I need to pass the `DH` classes methods to a function that is defined outside the class.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is to pass it as an argument

```
class EG {
     public $var;
     public function __construct( DH $dh ) {
         $this -> var = $dh;
     }
}
```

It's called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [it is preferred to extending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

I must add that sometimes inheritance is the correct way to go, but the way you describe your situation makes it seem like DI is the way to go.

Comment: The code doesn't work, do I have to pass it like this instead `__construct($dh = new DH())`?

Comment: Using your construct function exactly how you have type it I get the following error, `Argument 1 passed to EG::__construct() must be an instance of DH, none given`

Comment: You have to pass it an instance of DH or you can leave that out and add a setter that would pass a DH object

Comment: Or `__construct(DH $dh = NULL)` and test for `NULL` when dealing with that object.